# Which is Better, Creating separate Dataframe or referencing the dataframe with same name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Good day.

I am new to spark.I was hoping to get an suggestion on which is better
1. Creating a new dataframe each time a new transformation is done
2. Using the same name as the previous dataframe name after transformation

I have gone through other stackoverflow questions and rdd and dataframe guides but i was not able to arrive at a solution.

Option 1:

```
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
df1=df.filter(col('country')=='India')
df2=df1.groupBy("State").agg(max("GDP"), sum("expense"))
```

Option 2:

```
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
df=df.filter(col('country')=='India')
df=df.groupBy("State").agg(max("GDP"), sum("expense"))
```

Does option 2 take less memory as at a point of time only the latest dataframe can be accessible while in option 1 at a point in time we can access all the dataframes.

Question 2: when does a dataframe gets destroyed (not be accessible) in a program, is it after the program gets completed ?

Comment: It makes practically no difference in terms of memory (negligible extra space for more references). All that's stored is the execution plan (read about spark's lazy execution). Thus the only benefit for option 1 is the ability to have references to each step in the transformation.

Comment: When in doubt, use; `df.explain()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark have a Lazy evaluation, so the data will be brought to driver after some action will executed (and not to any variable assign as traditional programming). This approaches don't have significant differences in memory usage. Maybe, what you could see more frequently (in books, tutorials, ...) is:

```py
df=spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")

df.filter(col('country')=='India') \
  .groupBy("State") \
  .agg(max("GDP"), sum("expense"))
```

But this is the same as the option 2.

The first option is useful when you want to execute actions on intermediary dataframes.